# Can you provide collection finders in Saxon-Js, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Tags: saxon-js

I'm attempting to run saxon-js on the command line to apply XSL 3 transformations currently working in another system with Saxon HE, because saxon-js looks like it can offer a lot more versatility.

I am essentially brand new to XSL so the learning curve is steep.

The error on which I am currently stuck is this:

> Transformation failure: Error FODC0002 at iati.xslt#90
> Unknown collection (no collectionFinder supplied)

The snippet of XSLT which triggers this is:

```
  <xsl:variable name="iati-codelists">
    <codes version="2.03">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/2.03/codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/non-embedded-codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
    </codes>
  </xsl:variable>
```

This intends to go to that directory and sweep up a collection of .xml files.

Looking at the saxon-js docs, I see no option to provide a collection finder.

Is this something implemented in Saxon HE (which is presently doing the work) and not currently in Saxon-Js? Or am I barking up a different but equally wrong tree?

Thanks!

Comment: See the `collectionFinder` option of the transform function http://saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!api/transform, I am currently not sure whether there is some built-in way to, at least for synchronous processing, have such paths resolved without providing your own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. However the collectionFinder doesn't seem to work asynchronously so it's not super useful if you are writing an asynchronous application.

I was able to get this to work with some hardcoding of the paths provided in the collections() in my node app as a proof of concept. Definitely is a better way to do this.

If this is your XML

```
<xsl:variable name="iati-codelists">
    <codes version="2.03">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/2.03/codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/non-embedded-codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
    </codes>
    <codes version="2.02">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/2.02/codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/non-embedded-codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
    </codes>
    <codes version="2.01">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/2.01/codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/non-embedded-codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
    </codes>
    <codes version="1.05">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/1.05/codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
    </codes>
    <codes version="1.04">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/1.04/codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
    </codes>
    <codes version="1.03">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../lib/schemata/1.03/codelist/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')" mode="get-codelists"/>
    </codes>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Before the transform runs this code creates an object of the collections. The keys are a part of the file path to the codelist directories which contain a series of xml docs. The values are Arrays of the xml documents converted into the format Saxon JS needs with SaxonJS.getResource(). It got a little tricky with having the Promises inside the object so I had to use Lodash.

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsPromises = fs.promises;

const SaxonJS = require('saxon-js');

// load codelists since collectionFinder can't be async
let codelistPaths = [
    "non-embedded-codelist/",
    "2.03/codelist/",
    "2.02/codelist/",
    "2.01/codelist/",
    "1.05/codelist/",
    "1.04/codelist/",
    "1.03/codelist/"
];
                
// this returns an object of the codelistPaths as Keys and an Array of resolved promises for the Values. these promises are grabbing the codelist XML files using SaxonJS.getResource
let resources = _.zipObject(codelistPaths, await Promise.all(_.map(codelistPaths, async (path) => {
    let files = await fsPromises.readdir("./IATI-Rulesets/lib/schemata/" + path);
    return await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
        return await SaxonJS.getResource({ type : 'xml', file : "./IATI-Rulesets/lib/schemata/" +  path + file })
    }))
})))         

// this pulls the right array of SaxonJS resources from the resources object
const collectionFinder = (url) => {
    if (url.includes("codelist")) {
        let path = url.split('schemata/')[1].split('?')[0]; // get the right filepath (remove file:// and after the ?
        return resources[path]
    } else {
        return []
    }
}

// Applying the XSLT3 Ruleset to IATI Files Using SaxonJS
let results = await SaxonJS.transform({
    stylesheetFileName: "path to your .sef.json",
    sourceFileName: "path to your input .xml",
    destination: "serialized",
    collectionFinder: collectionFinder
}, "async")
```

Full details in the Saxon-JS support forum:
https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4797?pn=1#change-16579